# Insert performance with and without Index

Tags: performance, neo4j

Was doing a couple of tests.

Based on some great suggestions by Wes etc., I have tuned some of the neo4j  properties with no cache to do insert on a large scale in a multithreaded environment and the performance is not bad.

However, when I introduce index (on the nodes), the performance degrades a lot. The difference is easily 5 fold. Are there configuration settings to make it better?

Thanks in advance,

Sachin

Neo4j version - 1.8.1; JVM - 1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting nodes (or relationships) into a Lucene index is costly. Lucene is a powerful but complex tool, designed for fulltext/keyword search. Compared with the bare database, it is rather slow.

This is why most bulk insert tools do the indexing asynchronously, like Michael's batch inserter:

http://jexp.de/blog/2012/10/parallel-batch-inserter-with-neo4j/

Some even circumvent transactions, or write the store files directly:

http://blog.xebia.com/2012/11/13/combining-neo4j-and-hadoop-part-i/

To improve performance, using a SSD disk could help. But as Neo4j is a fully ACID transactional database, and the Lucene index is tightly coupled with the transactions (which is a good thing), there's not much else you can do besides optimizing your infrastructure for best write performance.

Comment: +1 for good recommendations. I'm working on a program to write the store files directly in C. It's going to rock. But I don't plan to support indexes initially (or maybe ever)--haven't even looked at the lucene file format yet. The OP might consider writing the indexes after the nodes, in their own bulk transactions.

Comment: Wow, sounds interesting. The race for top Neo4j insert performance is on! :)

Comment: So far, 1B nodes in 82 seconds (no properties or rels, useless!). Almost have rels working--takes quite a bit more work to do rels.

Comment: 1M nodes, 1B rels in ~10 minutes (no properties). Required 33GB RAM to pre-calculate the files before dumping them to disk. Next I think I'll try memory mapped files to see how they compare.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this additional answer is still of use for anyone running Neo4j on an ext4 filesystem under Linux:

By trading some transaction safety (negligible on USV/battery-buffered systems or laptops), the write performance can be increased by a factor of 10-15!

Read more in this recent blog post: http://structr.org/blog/neo4j-performance-on-ext4